# how can a feed a file list into dpkg --get?

Tags: apt-get, dpkg

I can use 
    dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f 1 | tr '\n' ' ' > listpackages.txt

to fill a file with all my installed packages.

Is there a to install using dpkg or apt and reference the listpackages.txt file created above?

I want to be able to backup what I have installed as a package list, reinstall my distro and finally in one command install everything I had installed on the previous version.

-thanks u2!

Answer (score 1):

`` apt-get install `cat listpackages.txt` ``

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--set-selections` flag to do this.

To export the package list from one system: `dpkg --get-selections` followed by whatever filtering you want.

To re-import the list to another system, pipe it into `dpkg --set-selections`, and then run `aptitude install`.  The `dpkg --set-selections` command will only queue the install process; you then actually have to execute it.